# How to test Google fit api in emulator android

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, nexus-7

I know we can use nexus 7 or 5 for test the Google fit API. 
I like to know is there way to test the Google fit API in emulator.
I need to explain the reason to my client. So please guide me in the right way. 
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Create emulator wit google API. Read http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/how-to-create-android-avd-emulator-in-eclipse/

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I want to test google fit api which is a part of google play service and it need android L OS. So when i try sample app with emulator it show some error.

Answer (score 0):

***Set up an AVD for AndroidL***

You can set up [Android Virtual Devices (AVD)](https://developer.android.com/tools/devices/index.html) and use the emulator to build and test apps with the L Preview.

To create an AVD with the AVD Manager:

Install the L Preview SDK in your development environment, as described in [Setting Up the Preview SDK](https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html).

Follow the steps in [Managing AVDs with AVD Manager](https://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html).

Use the following settings:

- Device: Either Nexus 5 or Nexus 7
- Target: Android L (Preview) - API Level L

---

Reference : [Setting Up the L Developer Preview SDK](https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html)

Comment: When i create emulator and while i run getting this error .      "Google Play services out of date.  Requires 5208000 but found 5053030"

Comment: @rakkis Add `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="5208000"/>` into manifest inside application tag.

Comment: No luck it returns the same result after changing in manifest.      Note :I am using google fit api in that application.

Comment: As per the below link they mentioned only nexus 7 and Nexus 5 real devices so it may be the reason for that issues. "https://developers.google.com/fit/preview"

Comment: Yes. That may be the problem.

Comment: seems you are using old version ,just upgrade your google play service libs with version 6 or > 6. im sure it will solve ur problem @Rakkis

Comment: @Jigs Yes this was the problem he got while AndroidL preview available.